# LLVM: How to obtain true/false basic block successor of a BranchInst

Tags: llvm

Considering a basic block containing a `CmpInst` and a `BranchInst`, which has two successors. When the condition is true, the "true branch" will be executed. However, how can we obtain the true/false successor? If we could only identify them according to the index of each successor?

Comment: Trur corresponds to [getSuccessor(0)](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BranchInst.html#ad97f2e60cf22f15e0cf617af52309031) and false to …(1). If you mean that you want the successor actually used, then you have [fold the CmpInst to a constant](https://llvm.org/doxygen/ConstantFolding_8h.html) and pick successor depending on whether [that constant is true or false](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html#a882d55a6aa2028e1a5ad708b275334e0). If it can't be folded, then that means the value will only be available at runtime.

Comment: @arnt This should be an answer.

Comment: @yugr I didn't feel sure that it answered question... YaFengLuo, is it an answer?

Comment: To the best of our knowledge, the first operand of BranchInst is the "true" branch destination. What we worried about is whether the situation could be related to the predication of CmpInst, e.g., CmpEq or CmpNe.